# Struct.pack sends array instead just single int variable

Tags: python, struct

I have

```
check_paket = 0

check_paket = fragIndex                
check_header = struct.pack('!I', check_paket)
sock.sendto(check_header, (host, port))
```

And when I receive and unpack

```
check_fragIndex = 0

data, addr = self.sock.recvfrom(65489)
check_header = data[:4]
(check_fragIndex) = struct.unpack('!I', check_header)
print('SENDER: check_fragIndex:' +str(check_fragIndex))
```

`fragIndex` is set for example to `1` when sending so it prints this

```
SENDER: check_fragIndex:(1,)
```

Instead of `SENDER: check_fragIndex: 1`

It creates a string I guess, but why? I need that `fragIndex` as 4 byte integer number...

Comment: [Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#struct.unpack): *The result is a* **tuple** *even if it contains exactly one item*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`struct.unpack()` *always* returns a tuple. From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#struct.unpack):

> The result is a tuple even if it contains exactly one item.

You *appear* to try to use assignment to extract the one value, but you only used parentheses:

```
(check_fragIndex) = struct.unpack('!I', check_header)
```

`(check_fragIndex)` is just a parenthesised name, not a tuple, so no extraction is taking place; `check_fragIndex` is bound to the whole tuple that `struct.unpack()` returns. You need a *comma* to get that effect:

```
(check_fragIndex,) = struct.unpack('!I', check_header)
#               ^ the comma is crucial here
```

You can omit the parentheses altogether:

```
check_fragIndex, = struct.unpack('!I', check_header)
```

or just use indexing to extract the one result:

```
check_fragIndex = struct.unpack('!I', check_header)[0]
```

Comment: Oh my :D its really just that freakin comma? :D gotta be kiddin me :D thanks man